# JBotton doesnt get removed

Tags: jframe, jbutton

I made a jframe with 4 jbuttons,
and once I type a specific key, it removes jbutton and other buttons go down.

However, when I remove jbutton, it does not go away directly,
but it does if I re-size or minimize the jframe window.

Are there any problem with my code?
or maybe is it a problem with my computer?

```
public class View extends JFrame {
GamePanel _gamePanel;
DataModel _dm;
GameTile _tile1, _tile2, _tile3, _tile4;
ArrayList<GameTile> _gameTileList;

public View(DataModel dm) {
    this._dm = dm;

    _gamePanel = new GamePanel();

    _tile1 = new GameTile('a');
    _tile1.addKeyListener(new PressKeyHandler(this));
    _tile2 = new GameTile('b');
    _tile2.addKeyListener(new PressKeyHandler(this));
    _tile3 = new GameTile('c');
    _tile3.addKeyListener(new PressKeyHandler(this));
    _tile4 = new GameTile('d');
    _tile4.addKeyListener(new PressKeyHandler(this));

    _gameTileList = new ArrayList<GameTile>();

    this.setSize(300, 500);
    this.setVisible(true);

    _gamePanel.add(_tile1);
    _gamePanel.add(_tile2);
    _gamePanel.add(_tile3);
    _gamePanel.add(_tile4);

    // this.addKeyListener(new PressKeyHandler(this));

    this.add(_gamePanel);

    // this.pack();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    _dm.setView(this);
}

public GamePanel get_gamePanel() {
    return _gamePanel;
}

public GameTile get_gameTile(char letter) {
    GameTile tileToReturn = new GameTile(' ');
    switch (letter) {
    case 'a':
        tileToReturn = _tile1;
        break;
    case 'b':
        tileToReturn = _tile2;
        break;
    case 'c':
        tileToReturn = _tile3;
        break;
    case 'd':
        tileToReturn = _tile4;
        break;
    }
    return tileToReturn;
}

public ArrayList<GameTile> get_gameTileList() {
    return _gameTileList;
}

public void set_gameTileList(ArrayList<GameTile> _gameTileList) {
    this._gameTileList = _gameTileList;
}

public void removeTile(JPanel panel) {
}

public void update() {
    _gamePanel.remove(_gameTileList.get(0));
    // _gameTileList.get(0).setText(" ");
    // _gameTileList.get(0).setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    emptyTile(_gameTileList.get(0));

    _gamePanel.add(_gameTileList.get(0), 0);

    _gameTileList.remove(0);
}

public void emptyTile(GameTile tile) {
    tile.setText(" ");
    tile.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    tile.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

}
}


public class PressKeyHandler implements KeyListener {
View _view;

public PressKeyHandler(View view) {
    this._view = view;
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    switch (e.getKeyChar()) {
    case 'a':
        _view.get_gameTileList().add(_view.get_gameTile('a'));
        _view.update();
        break;
    case 'b':
        _view.get_gameTileList().add(_view.get_gameTile('b'));
        _view.update();
        break;
    case 'c':
        _view.get_gameTileList().add(_view.get_gameTile('c'));
        _view.update();
        break;
    case 'd':
        _view.get_gameTileList().add(_view.get_gameTile('d'));
        _view.update();
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("no tiles for tyeped letterl");
    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Comment: we have a programming challenge. But there's any code yet?

Comment: can u show the error ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just a novice, but did you try putting frame.pack(); wherever you removed the button? I had a similar problem like that a few days ago, where a button wouldn't show up until I enlarged the frame. Then i added frame.pack(); where I added the button, and it automatically resized.

Comment: do I still need to use frame.pack(), although I set size of frame?

Comment: I think you do, try it. And in frame.pack(); "frame" is the name of my frame. So I think you would use "whatever the name of your frame is".pack();